# No qualifying bean of type available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I am learning Spring Dependency Injections and to do so I wrote small simple code, but I constanstly get this error:

```
No qualifying bean of type available available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Service.java

```
package net.ddns.encante.test2.Spring.SpringTest2;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Service {

    void doService (){
        System.out.println("Service is running");
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package net.ddns.encante.test2.Spring.SpringTest2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    Service service;
    void doControl(){
        System.out.println("Controlling, move along");
    }
    void doServiceByController(){
        service.doService();
    }
}
```

SpringTest2Application.java

```
package net.ddns.encante.test2.Spring.SpringTest2;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTest2Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SpringTest2Application.class, args);

      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
      ctx.register(Controller.class);
      ctx.refresh();
      Controller ctrl = ctx.getBean(Controller.class);
      ctrl.doServiceByController();
   }
}
```

I tried different combinations of @Component and @Autowired annotations but it doesn't help.

Comment: So you use Spring Boot, bootstrap the application. Then totally ignore it and create a new configuration with only the controller and wonder where the other beans are? If you look at the [`run`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run(java.lang.Class%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method you will see it returns an `ApplicationContext`. Instead of createing a new one, use that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your code.

```java
SpringApplication.run(SpringTest2Application.class, args);
```

This already creates everything you need. However you discard it and try to shoehorn something in there.

```java
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.register(Controller.class);
ctx.refresh();
Controller ctrl = ctx.getBean(Controller.class);
ctrl.doServiceByController();
```

This will create another application context, and only for the `Controller` nothing else.

Instead, if you read the javadoc of the [`run`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run(java.lang.Class%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method you can see that that already returns an `ApplicationContext`. Which is the one you should be using in the first place.

```java
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringTest2Application.class, args);
Controller ctrl = ctx.getBean(Controller.class);
ctrl.doServiceByController();
```

Is all you need.